# Application erros while Deploying React app on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have created a React app and used webpack to bundle it. Now I am trying to  deploy the app on heroku. The build is successful but when I try to open the link I get "Application Error". Is it necessary to have server.js file on root level of your react app to delpoy on heroku.

I have modified my webpack and I think it's fine but still the same error.

//here is my webpack.common.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./index.jsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    publicPath: "/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]

}

// webpack.dev.js
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common');


module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode:'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
        hot: true
    }
});

I expect the app to get deployed on heroku but I am getting application error.
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace from the heroku logs?